# Laravel 4 include multiple views in route

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is it possible to include multiple view in route? What is the best practice for doing this, let say I want config file, header, content, and footer file to join and load in a view? If do it in the route, then I can easily change the content based on route request.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You need to take a futher look at Laravel's Blade templating.  With Blade templating, you can create layouts and cascade them onto each other really nicely.  For example, let's take the following routes...

*app/routes.php*

```
Route::get('about', function()
{
    return View::make('about');
});

Route::get('contact', function()
{
    return View::make('content')
});
```

As you can see, we have two different views for those two different request.  However, with Blade templating, and sections, we can create a master layout and only change the content that we need.  So, here is what our master layout would look like.

*app/views/layouts/master.blade.php*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Site Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>About</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    @yield('content')

</body>
</html>
```

This is our master layout.  We have our nav that will always stay the same, our HTML and head and everything that we don't want to write over and over again.  But, we are also using `yield` in blade to accept content and place it there.  This is where our actual views come into play from routes.php.

*app/views/about.blade.php*

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <p>This is the about me content.</p>
@endsection
```

We can simply extend the master layout, and place our content within the `content` section, which we can name anything we want.  Same with the other page, contact.

*app/views/contact.blade.php*

```
@extends('layouts.master')

@section('content')
    <p>This is the contact page content.</p>
@endsection
```

As you can see, it's not so much as including multiple views...but rather it's about extending different views and putting them together using Blade.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate way to include header / footer in another view will as below.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/blade#including-sub-views

```
<div>
@include('templates.header') // views/templates/header.blade.php

<form>
    <!-- Form Contents -->
</form>
```